# How to delete a channel using package name?

Tags: android, android-tv

I am trying to delete all channels from `android.media.tv`'s database using `ContentResolver` **using the app package name** like this

```kotlin
applicationContext.contentResolver.delete(
    TvContractCompat.Channels.CONTENT_URI,
    "${TvContractCompat.Channels.COLUMN_PACKAGE_NAME} = ?",
    arrayOf(currentAppPackageName)
)
```

but am getting

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: Selection not allowed for content://android.media.tv/channel
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:298)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Selection not allowed for content://android.media.tv/channel
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:547)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1684)
```

I am aware that we can delete the channel by `channelId`, but in my case, I don't have the channel ID. I simply wants to delete all channels created by the app.

- What am I missing ?

[Ref](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel)

Answer (score 0):

requests should be one at a time. did you used synchronized in utils class or look for any other requests. Or try changing the package name, sometimes package names that are reserved by Java/android cause SecurityException.

Comment: It's a single request to the contentResolver. The given package name is valid. Also, the `SecurityException` happens for `select` query also.